# Macbook pro with old VGA CRT blackness

Tags: windows-7, mac, display, external-display

I'm away from the office and trying to use my 13" 2009 Macbook pro, with an oldish 21' CRT VGA monitor. In Windows 7 it is detected and listed. Through the windows options it will not let me select, apply or change resolution of the monitor, and just says unble to save when I click apply. Through Nvidia panel, I can again see it but if I select it and click apply it just deselects it.

In OSX the display is not even listed.

Im using an official mini display port to VGA adaptor.

Any ideas? or is it likely the monitor Im trying to use is simply too rubbish. its a Philips 109B.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seemed to work even with correct drivers, I guess the monitor was either to old / or faulty.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 you probably don't have a matching driver. I did a [quick search](http://www.search.philips.com/search/search?q=109B&s=all&l=gb_en&h=all&o=consumer&x=7&y=3) on the Philips site and loaded up the relevant matchs and there doesn't seem to be any drivers for Vista or Windows 7.

I'd imagine the problem is effectively the same on the Mac, but I'm afriad I'm not a Mac user - hopefully someone with greater knowledge in that area can help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I downloaded the XP driver and tried to update the monitor via the device manager and it said it was up to date. I mostly use Windows on this machine, I just thought Id check the mac side to see if the same problem occurred there.